# Log function return with out of range message

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

All. I have the following code.

```
with filDelta as(select a.* from delta a
Where a.Pdelta>0
And a.oldprice between 0.0001 and 10000 
and a.new_closeD between 0.0001 and 10000
),

Incr as(
select  a.Symbol, log(a.oldprice,a.New_closeD) increase
From filDelta a
)

Select  a.symbol 
from Incr a
Where a.increase>=1.3459
```

However, it return me the error on the line where log() is located. Error is

> ORA-01428:  parameter'0' out of range
>       01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range"

But in my with clause, I already filter the value, why is that please?

Comment: Can you look at the execution plan or trace the execution? It looks like Oracle is rewriting the query (pushing the predicate into the CTE/subquery).

Comment: Thanks, I will check the CTE stepwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some data that [simulates the problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac0/1), it looks like Oracle optimiser is rewriting the query in a way that pushes the predicate to a different level, meaning your filters are being applied after it's calculated the log. You could avoid that with the `/* no_push_pred */` hint.

But you could also trap the condition in the same level before calling log:

```
with filDelta as(
  select a.* from delta a
  where a.Pdelta>0
  and a.oldprice between 0.0001 and 10000 
  and a.new_closeD between 0.0001 and 10000
),
Incr as(
  select a.Symbol,
    case when a.New_closeD <= 0 then null
      else log(a.oldprice,a.New_closeD) end increase
  From filDelta a
)
Select a.symbol 
from Incr a
where a.increase>=1.3459;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac0/6).

Or with fewer levels of CTE:

```
with filDelta as(
  select a.*
  from delta a
  where a.Pdelta>0
  and a.oldprice between 0.0001 and 10000 
  and a.new_closeD between 0.0001 and 10000
)
select a.Symbol
from filDelta a
where case when a.New_closeD <= 0 then null
  else log(a.oldprice,a.New_closeD) end >=1.3459;

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac0/10).
```

Or without a CTE at all:

```
select a.Symbol
from delta a
where a.Pdelta>0
and a.oldprice between 0.0001 and 10000 
and a.new_closeD between 0.0001 and 10000
and case when a.New_closeD <= 0 then null
  else log(a.oldprice,a.New_closeD) end >=1.3459;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac0/11).